# C error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand (using pointers)

Tags: c

```
struct student{
    int id;
    int score;
};

struct student* allocate(){
     /*Allocate memory for ten students*/
     struct student *dynamicStudent = malloc(10 * sizeof(struct student));
     /*return the pointer*/
     return dynamicStudent;
}

int main(){
    struct student* stud = NULL;

    /*call allocate*/
    stud = &allocate();
```

The code above where it says "stud = &allocate();" is where it's giving the lvalue error. This is part of a pointer assignment that I have to do and I can't figure out how to fix this problem. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Your function call is incorrect.
Change

```
stud = &allocate();
```

to

```
stud = allocate();
```

---

```
struct student* allocate (void)
{
     /* Allocate memory for ten students */
     struct student *dynamicStudent = malloc(10 * sizeof(struct student));

     /* Return the pointer */
     return dynamicStudent;
}
```

Since your function `allocate (void);` returns an pointer of type `struct student`, you can collect the return value in `stud` which is of the same type.

```
int main (void)
{
    /* call allocate  */
    struct student* stud = allocate();         // <-- Correct Function Call

    // …code using stud…

    free(stud);   // Don't forget to free what you allocate

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

& operator expects an l-value ( an expression referring to an object) operand where as the the function returns an r-value and applying & operator to an r-value operand will cause an error. as others noted in your case it can be solved by omitting & operator on assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Allocate returns a pointer so you don't need to use the &.